# Strange UINavigationItem behavior after using custom navigation transitioning animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I am doing a custom UINavigationController pop transition animation.
But having a strange bug, I've made a sample project to demonstrate the issue (Taken from https://github.com/objcio/issue5-view-controller-transitions)

An navigation-based app, 2 view controllers.

The first viewController has 2 bar button items on the navigationBar, a button in the middle of view to push to second viewController.

The second viewController has a left bar button item to pop to the first viewController.

If the second view controller has been dragged less than 50%, my custom animation will cancel the transition, and if it's over 50%, it'll finish the transition, pop the viewController. (Just like the system default)

However, if the transition was cancelled, the navigation item's on the first view controller will be over-ridded.

The "back" item will appear on first view controller, and the right bar button item will disappear.

This is the video to demonstrate: https://youtu.be/qg2lUKsNtzk

And the source code is on github: https://github.com/JohnnyTseng/issue5-view-controller-transitions

Could somebody point out where the problem is? I've been debugging this issue for whole day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 Apple add new default navigation behavior. You can swipe from left border of the screen to go back on navigation stack.

you can stop this by putting this code in application delegate.

```
 if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
```

you can read more over here [interactive pop gesture of navigation view controller](http://keighl.com/post/ios7-interactive-pop-gesture-custom-back-button/)